# Как реализовать плавное перемещение объекта из точки A в B?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу сделать момент, когда игрок переходит в игровую сцену перехватывать движение и сначала вести игрока скриптом:

```
public class PlayerWelcome : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float SpeedMove;

    private Rigidbody2D RB;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
    private Animator AM;

    private string currentAM;

    public Vector3 A;
    public Vector3 B;

    void Start()
    {
        RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        AM = GetComponent<Animator>();

        A = new Vector3(-5.4f, -4.77f, 0.1f);
        B = new Vector3(-5.4f, -0.63f, 0.1f);

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        WelcomeRoom();
    }

    IEnumerator WelcomeRoom()
    {
        transform.position = A;

        float step = SpeedMove / (A - B).magnitude;
        float progress = 0;

        while ((transform.position - B).sqrMagnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            progress += step * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(A, B, progress);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = B;
    }
```

Возникла проблема, что объект двигается, но не до нужной мне заданной точки. Он сдвигается, проще говоря, на пару миллиметров: [Видео](https://youtu.be/1vsOVCetsos)

Comment: Через `transform.Translate`, очевидно, см. прошлый мой ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: @aepot В `FixedUpdate`, `WelcomeRoom`, надо мне было дописать: `StartCoroutine`. 
transform.Translate - тоже работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
   -- WelcomeRoom();
   ++ StartCoroutine("WelcomeRoom");
}
```